# Dynamic self-referencing conditional in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, loops, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

**Goal**: Create a conditional statement in a list comprehension that (1) *dynamically* tests -- i.e., upon each iteration -- if the element is not in the list being comprehended given (2) the list is itself updated on each iteration.

**Background code:**

```
arr = [2, 2, 4]
l = list()
```

**Desired output:**

```
l = [2, 4]
```

**Desired behavior via for loop:**

```
for element in arr:
        if element not in l:
            l.append(element)
```

**Incorrect list comprehension *not* generating desired behavior:**

```
l = [element for element in arr if element not in l]
```

**Question restated**: How do I fix the list comprehension so that it generates the desired behavior, i.e., the desired output stated above?

Comment: You cannot alter the same list you are making the comprehension into

Comment: Do you need to use a list comprehension for this? Is a set OK?

Comment: If you simply want to remove duplicate you might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order

Comment: you could do `list(set(arr))` if you can use sets

Comment: I would use a set.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: This code isn't trying to; its trying to *access* the list it is building while it is being built, but with the same (lack of) success.

Comment: The name `l` is not bound to the result of the comprehension until the comprehension runs to completion.

Comment: Also, check out PEP 8 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. Using a lower case L as a single variable name is strongly advised against.

Comment: Another alternative (if you really want to us a comprehension for whatever reason) is to use enumerate to keep track of the element's position within the original list, like so: `[e for i, e in enumerate(arr) if e not in arr[i+1:]]`.

Comment: You denied what I said but said exactly the same, with few wording changes. As @MadPhysicist says, the name `l` is not yet bound. @SwiftsNamesake gave you a workaround.

Comment: @Remuze I prefer not to pep8 toy examples on SO.

Comment: You can't use a list comprehension because the list being generated doesn't have a named reference that you can use. You can create a list and use a generator to update it.  `l = [];l.append(e for e in arr if e not in l)`.

Comment: @tdelaney. Way ahead of you, but yes you can put it in a comprehension.

Comment: @tdelaney. Also, you want `extend`, not `append` for that, but clever nevertheless.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Oops... meant to do that. `l = [];l.extend(e for e in arr if e not in l)`

Comment: @tdelaney. Do I have your permission to add that to my answer?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I don't think encouraging people to follow a very common style guide is a bad thing. I find PyCharm's constant reminders regarding pep8 to be really useful in helping me present my code better.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - yeah, no problem. I only made it a comment because it wasn't a direct answer but I think it would be a good addition to yours.

Comment: @Remuze. Please see the first section of PEP8 after the introduction. The title is pretty self-explanatory. Here is a link: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id13. Here is a link explaining the origin of the term bikeshedding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality

Comment: re. the bikeshedding and the lowercase l, I'll add that, as you discover the joys of pdb in debugging, you learn not to use 1 letter variable names that clash with pdb commands.

Answer (score 4):

If you absolutely must use a list comprehesion, you can just recast your `for` loop into one. The downside is that you will end up with a list of `None` elements, since that is what `list.append` returns:

```
>>> arr = [2, 2, 4]
>>> l = list()
>>> _ = [l.append(element) for element in arr if element not in l]
>>> print(l)
[2, 4]
>>> print(_)
[None, None]
```

If you are tied to comprehensions, but not necessarily to list comprehensions, you can use the generator comprehension suggested by @tdelaney. This will not create any unwanted byproducts and will do exactly what you want.

```
>>> arr = [2, 2, 4]
>>> l = list()
>>> l.extend(element for element in arr if element not in l)
```

A better way than either would probably be to put the original list into a set and then back into a list. The advantage of using a set to extending a list is that sets are much faster at adding elements after checking for prior containment. A list has to do a linear search and reallocate every time you add an element.

```
>>> l = list(set(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove duplicates why not use **set**(*the list containing duplicates*) or **list(dict.fromkeys**(*the list containing duplicates*)?

but to answer your Question:

i think the whole thing is just  wrong, l (your list) doesn't get updated with each iteration since it's inside the list comprehension